# Selection sort with stepped output in java

Tags: java

New to the site and have had some formal Java training.

A problem has been presented for a selection sort algorithm.

```
From the input of an array [ 80 50 -5 9 25 365]

Pass 1 [-5 365]
Pass 2 [-5 9 80 365]
Pass 3 [-5 9 25 50 80 365]
```

The selection sort isn't an issue, it is how to pull the data out in such a manner.

Any help or suggestions?

Comment: So, If I understand this correctly, at each iteration, you want to select the lowest and highest numbers, and put them on opposite sides of your array?

Comment: I dont know if i understand your question correctly. You want to fill future sorted array in these steps? If is that so. You have to keep your positions at the beggining and at the end of result array. After each pass you increment current left(beggining) and decrement right(end) position

Comment: @Sam I am: That is what I'm looking to understand how to do with this a given problem. Opposite sides of an array for the pass and in the sorted order.

Comment: @charonodaemon  what specifically do you not understand.  Can you make a basic program?  can you make a loop?  can you swap elements of an array?

Answer (score 0):

There is actually an issue with your passes, because you can't randomly insert and remove elements from an array.  arrays don't support that.

The reason why you might be confused, is because your algorithm is confusing because, as written, it **actually** doesn't make sense.

I'm going to give you a big hint.  Think of your passes in this way

```
Pass 1 [-5 ... 365]
Pass 2 [-5 9 ... 80 365]
Pass 3 [-5 9 25 50 80 365]
```

where the `...` represents the rest of the elements in your array.  It doesn't matter what order they are in